# Adding image to rectangle while keeping the color rectangle was previously filled with

Tags: c#, wpf

On WPF C# I try to make a chess game. I have filled every square with color as a Rectangle, and now I want to put a image of a chesspiece on it while keeping the color under the chess piece.
as I see I have hard times keeping both, weather I can keep the color or the chesspiece image.
is it possible to keep both? if it is not, is there another way to make it look as a chesspiece on colored square?

I have a Rectangle

```
   `<Rectangle x:Name="a1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7" Fill="#ebecd0"/>`
```

this just puts a chess piece instead of color

```
   `            Image myImage = new Image();
        BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        myBitmapImage.BeginInit();
        myBitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Images/bishop_b.png");
        myBitmapImage.EndInit();
        myImage.Source = myBitmapImage;
        a1.Fill = new ImageBrush(myBitmapImage);`
```

Comment: You would typically have an Image element as the child of a Border element in each grid cell. As a note, the Image you currently have in your code sample is totally redundant. It is not used anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Rectangle inside Border so you can keep the background and put any image you want in the rectangle :

**XML:**

```
<Border x:Name="a1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7" Background="#ebecd0">
        <Rectangle x:Name="a1_rectangle"/>
    </Border>
```

**Code.cs:**

```
    // the new code to fill:
    a1_rectangle.Fill = new ImageBrush(myBitmapImage);

    //and to clear the rectangle image use this:
    //a1_rectangle.Fill = null;
```

Comment: Now you could also use a simpler Image element instead of a Rectangle with an ImageBrush.